# How do I access my GeoJSON data after I deserialised it into an object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, geojson, json-deserialization

I have created a `Java` object by deserialising `JSON` file using `Jackson`. I want to render the data in the map template provided but I am not sure how to access it.

Below is the code and the `JSON` file. Am I on the right track? Someone advised that I can access the object if I use that `Feature` class in the main method.  Something like ex: `Feature obj = new Feature();` then access any of the variables by using `obj.getType()`. I want to access the whole file actually so it renders that data shows up on the `WorldWind Map`.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [102.0, 0.6]
            },
            "properties": {
                "prop0": "value0"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "prop1": 0.0,
                "prop0": "value0"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0],
                        [100.0, 0.0]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "prop1": {
                    "this": "that"
                },
                "prop0": "value0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my code:

```
public class NetworkVisualizer extends ApplicationTemplate {

  public static class AppFrame extends ApplicationTemplate.AppFrame {

    public AppFrame() {
      super(true, true,
            false);

      // Size the World Window to take up the space typically used by the layer panel.
      Dimension size = new Dimension(1400, 800);
      this.setPreferredSize(size);
      this.pack();
      WWUtil.alignComponent(null, this, AVKey.CENTER);

      makeMenu(this);
    }


    protected static void makeMenu(final AppFrame appFrame) {
      final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("JSON File", "json", "json"));

      JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
      appFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
      JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
      menuBar.add(fileMenu);

      JMenuItem openFileMenuItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Open File...") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
          try {
            int status = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(appFrame);
            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

              //TODO Likely need to start here when handling parsing of GeoJSON!

              @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
              @JsonPropertyOrder({
                      "type",
                      "geometry",
                      "properties"
              })
              class Feature {

                @JsonProperty("type")
                private String type;
                @JsonProperty("geometry")
                private Geometry geometry;
                @JsonProperty("properties")
                private Properties properties;
                @JsonIgnore
                private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                @JsonProperty("type")
                public String getType() {
                  return type;
                }

                @JsonProperty("type")
                public void setType(String type) {
                  this.type = type;
                }

                @JsonProperty("geometry")
                public Geometry getGeometry() {
                  return geometry;
                }

                @JsonProperty("geometry")
                public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
                  this.geometry = geometry;
                }

                @JsonProperty("properties")
                public Properties getProperties() {
                  return properties;
                }

                @JsonProperty("properties")
                public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
                  this.properties = properties;
                }

                @JsonAnyGetter
                public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
                  return this.additionalProperties;
                }

                @JsonAnySetter
                public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
                  this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
                }
              }
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      });

      fileMenu.add(openFileMenuItem);


    }




  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final AppFrame af = (AppFrame) start("World Wind JSON Network Viewer", AppFrame.class);
  }
}
```

Here is where I am getting the error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final AppFrame af = (AppFrame) start("World Wind JSON Network Viewer", AppFrame.class);

    File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FeatureCollection features = objectMapper.readValue(selectedFile, FeatureCollection.class);

  }
```

jfc is saying create local variable
readValue is throwing an unhandled exception

Comment: Are you really defining a class in an if statement? That can't be legal....?

Comment: Well I guess it is... but don't do that.... that makes the code so ugly and hard to read

Answer (score 2):

For working with [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) `JSON` payloads you can use for example, [geojson-jackson](https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson) library which is available in [1.12](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.grundid.opendatalab/geojson-jackson/1.12) version. To use it you just need to add it to your `Maven` configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.grundid.opendatalab</groupId>
    <artifactId>geojson-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Since now you can read your `JSON` configuration as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.geojson.FeatureCollection;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GeoJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        FeatureCollection features = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, FeatureCollection.class);
        features.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Feature{properties={prop0=value0}, geometry=Point{coordinates=LngLatAlt{longitude=102.0, latitude=0.6, altitude=NaN}} GeoJsonObject{}, id='null'}
Feature{properties={prop1=0.0, prop0=value0}, geometry=LineString{} MultiPoint{} Geometry{coordinates=[LngLatAlt{longitude=102.0, latitude=0.0, altitude=NaN}, LngLatAlt{longitude=103.0, latitude=1.0, altitude=NaN}, LngLatAlt{longitude=104.0, latitude=0.0, altitude=NaN}, LngLatAlt{longitude=105.0, latitude=1.0, altitude=NaN}]} GeoJsonObject{}, id='null'}
Feature{properties={prop1={this=that}, prop0=value0}, geometry=Polygon{} Geometry{coordinates=[[LngLatAlt{longitude=100.0, latitude=0.0, altitude=NaN}, LngLatAlt{longitude=101.0, latitude=0.0, altitude=NaN}, LngLatAlt{longitude=101.0, latitude=1.0, altitude=NaN}, LngLatAlt{longitude=100.0, latitude=1.0, altitude=NaN}, LngLatAlt{longitude=100.0, latitude=0.0, altitude=NaN}]]} GeoJsonObject{}, id='null'}
```

As you can see, you have an access to each property in very structured way. You do not need to create your own `POJO`, just use already implemented and tested `POJO` model. In your example you can do that in this way:

```
if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FeatureCollection features = objectMapper.readValue(selectedFile, FeatureCollection.class);
}
```

See also:

- [Java Swing – JFileChooser example](https://www.mkyong.com/swing/java-swing-jfilechooser-example/)

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. 
I have tried both methods that you suggested. Both did not want to cooperate. The first method which was using the GeoJSON did not work and it did not print out the line as suggested.  
The second method using the POJO did not want to cooperated. I am going to throw thew errors I am getting in the post.

Comment: @brianmsantos, I see you have basic problems with `Java`. Please, try read first some tutorials: [Methods in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-methods), [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial), [The Java File Class](https://www.baeldung.com/java-io-file), [others](https://www.baeldung.com/tag/core-java/). After that it should be easier for you to spot a problem. You mixed many concepts, variables are misused and method declaration is wrong. Also, you should not declare second `main` method in your app. You need to learn how to pass params.